# How to avoid that Gradle's osgi plugin generates export-pacakge entry for private packages and import-package entry for embedded dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, osgi, bnd

Dear StackOverflow users

I have a gradle project of which I want to turn the artifact into an osgi bundle. In this bundle I have:

- packages that I don't want to export (may not appear in manifest's `Export-Package` entry)
- dependencies that I want to embed (may not appear in manifest's `Import-Package` entry)

After a bit of tinkering I have come up with the following `gradle.build` file which does what I intend but maybe not in the cleanest way possible, leveraging bnd...

```
group 'com.mycompany'
version '1.0.0'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'osgi'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies{
    compile 'org.osgi:org.osgi.framework:1.8.0'  //provided
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'    //embedded
}


jar {
    //embedding the gson dependency
    from({
        def x = configurations.compile.find({
            return it.getName().contains('gson')
        })
        def tree = zipTree(x)
        return tree
    })

    //explicitly building manifest entries
    manifest {
        instruction 'Bundle-Vendor',
                'My Company'
        instruction 'Bundle-Activator',
                'com.mycompany.mybundle.Activator'
        instruction 'Import-Package',
                '!com.google.gson',           
                '*'
        instruction 'Export-Package',
                /com.mycompany.mybundle;version="${version}"/
    }
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish this in a cleaner way?  I mainly want to avoid two things:

1. having to manually write the import and export-package entries
2. having to manually copy the contents of the embedded dependencies (gson) into my jar

I thought bnd (underlying the osgi plugin) could do that for me, but with what I have tried so far (even if I add them as private package) bnd still exports everything and imports the gson package as well as it won't add the gson classes to the jar

Answer (score 4):

You would be better off using the [Bnd Gradle plugin](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle/README.md) for OSGi. It is written and supported by the developers of bnd who know a thing or two about OSGi.

Comment: In your case, you probably should look at the Bnd Gradle plugin for non-workspace builds: biz.aQute.bnd.builder. https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle#gradle-plugin-for-non-workspace-builds